# I have a problem Django , authViews.LoginView.as_view(template_new="")

Tags: python, django

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as authViews
```

is that module
My code

```
path("user/", authViews.LoginView.as_view(template_new="users/user.html"), name="user"),
path("exit/", authViews.LogoutView.as_view(template_new="users/exit.html"), name="exit"),
```

My problem is server does not see as_view(template_new="")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `TemplateView` (and its subclasses like `LoginView`) have an attribute called `template_name`, not `template_new`.

This should be easily fixed with:

```py
path("user/", authViews.LoginView.as_view(template_name="users/user.html"), name="user"),
path("exit/", authViews.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="users/exit.html"), name="exit"),
```